# How to add sold out text next to product variant in drop down if variant is our of stock?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce variants products, I have managed to disable the variant option in the drop down if the variants has all its products out of stick. What I want to do though is also add a 'Sold Out' text next to the disabled variant value in the drop down menu.

How can this be done:

```
/**
 * Disable out of stock variations
 * https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/826af31e1e3b6e8e5fc3c1004cc517c5c5ec25b1/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php
 * @return Boolean
 */

function wcbv_variation_is_active( $active, $variation ) {
 if( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
 return false;
 }
 return $active;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'wcbv_variation_is_active', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the instructions here and modify the sold out text to be what you would like :
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-sold-out-to-woocommerce-variable-product-dropdown/

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work. It didn't disable the drop down item or showed the sold out message. I pasted the last code snippet from that link you sent me to my functions.php and didn't work..Can you give me clearer instructions in case I'm dong something wrong?